# Tomcat 6.0.26 caching Java classes

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, tomcat6

I am facing a wierd issue suddenly and I am out of wits why this would happen.

My basic setup is to use maven (eclipse plugin 0.20), Tomcat 6.0.26.

Until few days back i was able to start tomcat in debug mode, make changes in code while debugging and test them. Then later run prepare-package for maven, stop and start tomcat to reflect the changes.

But since couple of days, debug option stopped working and eclips was not loading the changes from the class correctly. I initially thought it to be a debug issue, but then even if I stopped tomcat, ran a prepare package and started tomcat, my class changes do not show up.

I normally keep build automatically true in eclipse which writes the class file to target/classes and maven copies it to WEB-INF/classes from where tomcat reads it. Toggling this option helped prepare-package to work only sometimes.

I am not sure if this may be an issue with my maven-plugin or tomcat doing some wierd caching of classes. These are not servlet or JSPs but normal java classes.

Wanted to know if someone saw this kind of issue or is it just my machine giving me trouble

Comment: How do you start Tomcat? WTP? Cargo? Externally? Are you using Workspace resolution?

Comment: I start tomcat from command line using catalina jpda start command

Comment: Ohh, you're using hot code replacement via debugger. So it depends on whether the class can be replaced, e.g. the signatures stay the same etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a small web application, deploy it to tomcat from eclipse, debug it, modify the code and see if its auto deployed..It that works, you could try deleting your eclipse project and reimporting and rebuilding it

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resoved. my application had two jar(some content but different names only) having same class (same package hierarchy) with different versions. so when i was trying to debug, it was picking older one. i removed the older jar and problem is solved.

Thanks